# Getting random image file from Resources in VB.Net (2022), which then displays in a picturebox

Tags: vb.net

Im doing something for programming class, which involves making a 'Snap!' game.

Basically the code runs like this:

```
Private Sub btnOne_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOne.Click
        picOne.Visible = True 'displays picOne'
        lblDisplay.Text = "Owl" 'changes text of lblDisplay to "Owl"
        btnOne.Enabled = False 'btnOne is disabled, making it impossible to click it.
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnTwo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTwo.Click
        picTwo.Visible = True 'displays picOne'

        If lblDisplay.Text = "Bee" Then 'Checks if lblDisplay is "Bee"
            lblDisplay.Text = "Snap!" 'displays 'Snap!' statement above is true
        Else
            lblDisplay.Text = "Bee" 'otherwise, just displays bee, as duplicate isnt found
        End If

        btnTwo.Enabled = False 'btnTwo is disabled, making it impossible to click it.
    End Sub
```

However, this is extremely boring, as the same two cards will always be 'Snap!' I need a way so that a random image is selected from 'Resources,' and is then displayed in a picture box.

I'm not sure how I would go about getting a random image from resources, so if anyone could help me with this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: [Two options here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93e746fe-09f1-40b0-b57d-9331a9ad3440/how-do-i-load-a-random-pic-from-resources-please-?forum=vbgeneral). Either make a List and manually add all the images, or enumerate all resources and look for Bitmaps within.

Comment: You know what images you have in resources so hard-code their names in a `String` array, generate a random index into that array, get the name and then get the resource with that name from the resource manager.

Answer (score 0):

You know what images you have in resources so you can hard-code their names in a `String` array, generate a random index into that array, get the name and then get the resource with that name from the resource manager.

```vb
Dim imageResourceNames = {"Image1", "Image2", "Image3"}
Dim rng As New Random
Dim index = rng.Next(imageResourceNames.Length)
Dim imageResourceName = imageResourceNames(index)
Dim img = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageResourceName), Image)
```

If you prefer not to hard-code the resource names, you can get them using similar logic to one of the answers provided in the link in the comments:

```vb
Private Function GetResourceImageNames() As String()
    Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = GetType(My.Resources.Resources).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
                                                                                     BindingFlags.Instance Or
                                                                                     BindingFlags.Static)
    Dim imageType As Type = GetType(Image)

    Return properties.Where(Function(pi) imageType.IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType)).
                      Select(Function(pi) pi.Name).
                      ToArray()
End Function
```

and:

```vb
Dim imageResourceNames = GetResourceImageNames()
Dim rng As New Random
Dim index = rng.Next(imageResourceNames.Length)
Dim imageResourceName = imageResourceNames(index)
Dim img = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageResourceName), Image)
```

Getting the names first and then getting just the one desired `Image` is more efficient than getting all `Images` and discarding all but one. Of course, if you plan to use all or most of the `Images`, then it might make sense to get them all into an array first and then use that array over and over to get random `Images`.

Comment: Thanks for answering quickly! Is there a specific reason as to why someone wouldn't want to hardcode resources?

Comment: hey, I've tried your second solution, however ```PropertyInfo()``` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @verygood101, you need to be far more specific than "doesn't seem to work". You have to tell us what you actually did and what actually happened. If there's an error message, tell us what it is and where it was generated. My guess is that you just didn't bother importing the appropriate namespace. You ALWAYS have to specify the namespace of a type, either by qualifying the type name or importing the namespace.

Comment: @verygood101, as for hard-coding such values, it's generally avoided so as not to violate the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). If you hard-code the values then any change you make to resources later will require a corresponding change in that hard-coding. If you use code to determine the appropriate values at run time then that will account for any changes you may make in future. Often times, people will assume that they won't make changes later and they are often correct, but you'd be surprised how many time they aren't. If you hard-code and forget to update later, your code is broken.